# Python second class initialization

Tags: python

I have my first task on python class:

- Create a module `vectors.py`
- It will be a class definition `MyVector`
- constructor will accept one parameter, which will be one-dimensional array.
- `get_vector()` method returns one-dimensional array containing the elements of the vector.
- using a special method `__ mul__(self, other)` implement the dot product of two objects of type MyVector. The output is a scalar (a single number).

Now it's seems like this:

```
class MyVector:
    def __init__(self,vector=[]):
        self.vector=vector

    def get_vector(self):
        return (self.vector)        

    def __mul__(self,other):
        dot=sum(p*q for p,q in zip(self.vector, WHAT IS HERE?))
        return(dot)
```

I have first vector, but how can I initialize second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume that the `other` parameter for the special `__mul__` method is an instance of `MyVector`, then that instance will also have an attribute named `vector` which you can access:

```
def __mul__(self,other):
    dot=sum(p*q for p,q in zip(self.vector, other.vector))
    return (dot)
```

and don't use `[]` as default value in function arguments, use something like this :

```
 def __init__(self,vector=None):
    self.vector=vector if vector else []
```

Comment: Using `None` as a "sentinel", then `self.vector = vector if vector is not None else []` is perhaps more correct. Also, more for the OP, it's probably best to use `other.get_vector()` to preserve duck typing and preserve an interface to a class